# configure nginx to redirect to new URL

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter, nginx

I have a Wordpress site run on nginx which calls a Code Igniter URL from a Wordpress template to display page inside Wordpress page.

I would like to configure nginx.conf to redirect from url `/register/new_registration` to `/register/?param=new_registration`.

I tried

```
location /register {
  # rewrite anything start with /register but not /register/?param=
  if ($request_uri ~ "^(?!\/register/\?param=).*") {
    rewrite ^/register/(.*)$ /register/?param=$1;
  }

  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

But didn't work. How do I configure this?
Thanks,

Comment: If you want `rewrite` to perform a redirect, you need to add the keyword `redirect` or `permanent`.